# Linking external packages as library?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, cmake

So I am still pretty new to linux and CMake, I want to add an **X package** as Library to a currently existing program. The instructions say *Now, link the X library to your project by extending the target_link_libraries command of your executable:*

```
target_link_libraries(target-name X package [other-libraries])
```

What does the executable mean? Does it mean the name of the executable file .sh ? or the project name in  CMakeLists.txt as adding the latter gives this cmake error:

```
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:79 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "Simulation" which is not built by
  this project.
```

Thank you for any advice!

EDIT 1: CMakeList.txt as requested

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0079 NEW)
# Set project name:
project(Simulation)

########## The project ##########
# Traverse source folder and find extra includes.
file(GLOB_RECURSE files ABSOLUTE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} *.h *.hh)

option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build package with shared libraries." OFF)

set(last_include_path "")

foreach(file ${files} )
    get_filename_component(path ${file} PATH)

    # Check if the path has not been processed before.
    string(COMPARE EQUAL "${path}" "${last_include_path}" already_included)
    if(NOT ${already_included})
        # Adapt last_include_path.
        set(last_include_path "${path}")
        # Add include path if include subdirectory exits.
        if(IS_DIRECTORY ${path})
            message(STATUS "Added include: ${path}")
            include_directories(${path})
        endif()
    endif()
endforeach()

# make documentation (after all subproject (which add dependencies to the documentation) are build):
add_custom_target(documentation ALL
                COMMAND echo Creating documentation
                COMMAND rm -rf ../documentation
                COMMAND mkdir -p ../documentation
                COMMAND doxygen GODDeSS.dox > /dev/null
                WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
# add_custom_command(TARGET documentation
#                      POST_BUILD
#                      COMMAND echo ARGS Creating documentation pdf-files
#                      COMMAND sed ARGS -e "s#makeindex#makeindex -q#" -i Makefile
#                      COMMAND make all > /dev/null
#                      COMMAND cp refman.pdf ../documentation.pdf
#                      COMMAND touch ../documentation.html
#                      COMMAND echo ARGS \"<html> <head> <meta http-equiv=\\\"refresh\\\" content=\\\"0\\; URL=html/index.html\\\"/> </head> </html>\" > ../documentation.html
#                      WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../documentation/latex)

# Add subdirectories which contain CMakeLists, too (they will be executed after this project or, if this project depends on them, before this project):
message(STATUS "Added subproject: ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Simulation")
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Simulation)
message(STATUS "Added subproject: ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/G4BasicObjects")
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/G4BasicObjects)


#added G4Sipm

add_subdirectory(externals/g4sipm)
include_directories(externals/g4sipm/g4sipm/include)  
include_directories(externals/g4sipm/externals/gtest/include) 
target_link_libraries(Simulation g4sipm boost_date_time)
```

Comment: is that x package already installed or you are adding as submodule?

Comment: `as adding the latter gives this cmake error:` Please show your cmakelists.txt `Cannot specify link libraries for target "Simulation"` Before you can `target_link_libraries` you need to `add_library` or `add_executable`

Comment: @UmarFarooq the package is not installed, I added as a submodule.

Comment: @KamilCuk I have added CMakeList.txt in the edit.

Comment: So where is `add_library(Simulation)` or `add_executable(Simulation)`? `file(GLOB_RECURSE files ABSOLUTE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` there is no such syntax [cmake doc file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#glob-recurse)

Comment: More precisely, there is no `ABSOLUTE` flag to `GLOB_RECURSE`, only `RELATIVE`.

Comment: @KamilCuk @DevSolar  ah the code is old as it was written in 2014/2015. Would adding 
     `add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})` suffice ?

Comment: Could be, try it

Comment: Check if Simulation/CmakeLists.txt contains any add_executable statements.

Comment: Please check the documentation of the tools (and commands) you are using. `add_executable()` takes a target name (which may or may not be identical to your project name, as a project may have more than one library / executable target), and a *list of source files* (not directories).

Comment: @KamilCuk I tried it and got this error CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:80 (add_executable):
  `add_executable cannot create target "Simulation" because another target
  with the same name already exists.  The existing target is a static library
  created in source directory "/home/abhinab1/goddess/source" `

Comment: @Botje @DevSolar  under Simulation/CmakeLists.txt I have `add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} RunSimulation.cc ${sources} ${headers})` I applied it and added `target_link_libraries(RunSimulation g4sipm boost_date_time) ` which does build and pass cmake.